# Links are not visible in On Hold message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Links in On Hold message under posts are not visible. They are in black, as all the surrounding text.

[image]

("help center" has been clicked upon, but "edit the question" and "leave a comment" are not discernable)

**Feature request**: underline these links. (or, alternatively, change color scheme)

Answer (score 2):

There's already a style rule in the site CSS that seems to be intended to underline links in the message box:

```
.question-status h2 a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Unfortunately, because of the `h2` in the selector, it *only* applies to the username links in the message header (where it's actually redundant, since *all* links inside `h2` headers in the main content area are already underlined by another rule).

Simply changing this rule to:

```
.question-status a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

is sufficient to fix this bug.

Ps. I've included this rule (for skeptics.SE only) in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14 user script.  I had to add an `!important` tag to it to make it also apply to `:hover` links without specificity hacks.